# Needed aid with complicated MySQL query - very narrow scope

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Here are my TABLES described and their contents:
users:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| public_key_path | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email           | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pbox            | varchar(50)  | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

contents:

```
+----+-------------------+----------------------+--------+
| id | public_key_path   | email                | pbox   |
+----+-------------------+----------------------+--------+
| 33 | /path/to/pubkey1/ | FirstUser@email.com  | Pbox01 |
| 34 | /path/to/pubkey2/ | SecondUser@email.com | Pbox02 |
| 35 | /path/to/pubkey3/ | ThirdUser@email.com  | Pbox03 |
+----+-------------------+----------------------+--------+
```

files:

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| file_path | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| owner_id  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

contents:

```
+-----+-----------------+----------+
| id  | file_path       | owner_id |
+-----+-----------------+----------+
| 104 | /path/to/file1/ |       33 |
| 105 | /path/to/file2/ |       34 |
| 106 | /path/to/file3/ |       35 |
| 107 | /path/to/file4/ |       33 |
| 108 | /path/to/file5/ |       33 |
| 109 | /path/to/file6/ |       34 |
+-----+-----------------+----------+
```

encrypted_symmetric_keys:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| key_path | varchar(100) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| file_id  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

contents:

```
+-----+---------------------+---------+---------+
| id  | key_path            | file_id | user_id |
+-----+---------------------+---------+---------+
| 106 | /path/to/key1forU1/ |     104 |      33 |
| 107 | /path/to/key2forU2/ |     105 |      34 |
| 108 | /path/to/key3forU3/ |     106 |      35 |
| 109 | /path/to/key4forU1/ |     107 |      33 |
| 110 | /path/to/key5forU1/ |     108 |      33 |
| 111 | /path/to/key6forU2/ |     109 |      34 |
| 112 | /path/to/key3forU1/ |     106 |      33 |
| 113 | /path/to/key2forU1/ |     105 |      33 |
| 114 | /path/to/key6forU1/ |     109 |      33 |
+-----+---------------------+---------+---------+
```

This is a newbie database for a server that stores filepaths that are encrypted with encrypted symmetric keys(ESKs).
If there is key_path `/path/to/key1forU1/` that means that the key is stored for file1 for user1.
I need a query that, when given file_path (ex. "/path/to/file1/") lists all users that have access to this file.
Let me know if you need any more information, I'll provide it immediately.
I know that this is a very localized question, but I've been thinking for more than an hour about that now and I'm having horrible problems with wrapping my head around it.

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT:

My final set of data I need is, when given
 '/path/to/file1/'
 would return
FirstUser@email.com

But when given for example
/path/to/file2/'
would return
FirstUser@email.com
SecondUser@email.com
because

Comment: Just join the tables you need. If I understand your question correctly, to list the emails of users, use something like `select email from users join files on owner_id = users.id join encrypted_symmetric_keys on users.id = user_id and files.id = file_id where files.file_path = "/path/to/file1/"`

Comment: what is the final data set that you need? do you need a list of all user_id for each key_path?

Comment: Yeah I've been trying that, but I never got it to work exactly like the way I want it to. Yours works way better than any of my iterations, but displays only 1 email, the one who is an owner of the given file (owner_id). I need it to display everyone who has access to it, or everyone but the owner(doesn't matter which, both will work for my purposes). So for `/path/to/file1/` it would be `FirstUser@email.com`, but for file3 it would be 2 emails, Third and First users.

Comment: I edited with the final set needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for
as this will give you all email that are using `file_path = '/path/to/file6/'` except the owner's email

```
SELECT su.email
FROM encrypted_symmetric_keys AS c 
INNER JOIN users AS su ON su.id = c.user_id
INNER JOIN files AS f ON f.id = c.file_id AND f.owner_id <> c.user_id
WHERE f.file_path = '/path/to/file6/'
```

Comment: looks good now. probably change last where to file_path instead of key_path, as input is file path

Comment: This seems to work, that's not something I could come up with. What does <> mean?
Also, is modifying it to display all emails including the owner email hard? I can't do it on the first glance, but I'll try for practice.

Comment: <> or != mean NOT EQUAL TO   I am glad it worked for you